# I have trouble with CSS styling

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make my page looks like this :

[image: the image]

Here is an album of what i've cut ...

https://plus.google.com/photos/107900027460905004143/albums/5701903548070918369?authkey=CNjam-nOwZzxSg

So, here is my CSS (sub table is the top part)

```
body 
{
   font-family : Segoe UI;
}

.main_table
{
    width : 702px;
    border:0px;
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-width:0px;
    border-style:none;  
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:0px;
}


.sub_table
{
    background-image:url('../images/header_l.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    width:47.5%;
    }

.sub_table_r
{
    background-image:url('../images/header_r.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    width:47.5%;      
}

.content_table
{
    background-image:url('../images/content_left.png');
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:left;
    width:47.5%;
}

.content_table_r
{
    background-image:url('../images/content_right.png');
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:left;
    width:47.5%;
}

.centre_col
{
    background-image:url('../images/centre.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:5%;
    background-position:center;
}
.centre_top
{
    background-image:url('../images/top_centre.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:5%;
    background-position:bottom;
}

.centre_bottom
{
    background-image:url('../images/centre_bottom.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:5%;
    background-position:top;    
}

.Day
{
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:large;
}
.Year
{
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:large;
    color:Orange;
}

.Week
{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:large;
}

.Today
{
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:x-large;
    color:Navy;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.bottom
{
    background-image:url("../images/bottom.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    width:47.5%;

}

.bottom_r
{
    background-image:url("../images/bottom_r.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    width:47.5%;
}
```

and here is my HTML markup

```
<table class = "main_table">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="3">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create Events" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" class="sub_table">
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4" class="Today">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                        <td rowspan="4" class="Today">
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Today" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="Day">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Day">
                            <asp:Label ID="Month" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Week">
                            <asp:Label ID="Week" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Year">
                            <asp:Label ID="Year" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="centre_top">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left"  class="sub_table_r">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4" class="Today">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                        <td rowspan="4" class="Today">
                            <asp:Label ID="Tomorrow" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="Day">
                            <br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <br />
                           </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Day">
                            <asp:Label ID="Month0" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Week">
                            <asp:Label ID="Week0" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Year">
                            <asp:Label ID="Year0" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  class="content_table" align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="Content" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td  class="centre_col">
                         </td>
            <td  class="content_table_r">
                            <asp:Label ID="Content0" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  class="bottom" align="right">
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
            </td>
            <td  class="centre_bottom" align="center">
                            </td>
            <td class="bottom_r">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And this the output : (without content)

[image: Before content]

[image: after content]

[image: Preview in Expression web]

I really am baffled, and i think this problem had troubled me for a month . YOUR help is deeply appreciated .

Comment: Sorry, i am just desperate ...

Comment: Seriously, don't use tables for non-tabular data in the 21st century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use tables. Use `div` and relative positioning. Use background images to get the notebook look.

Comment: @aladdin - one trick I use is to use garish colours for divs during development - so you have see them eaasily.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Ed Heal sad. Don't use tables. Use div or section with background-image + position relative and fix width and height. Then should it work.

Tables are always tricky to understand (cells, column, border, etc...).